# Does GPS module need a wireless service? do I have to pay a service to get my gps module working?

Tags: gps

Hi I'm new in the GPS world, I'm looking for a GPS module to track X amount of object the question is do I have to pay any service (cellular, data,etc) to get my gps working? 
I'm sorry for the dumby question but I'm new here

thanks

Comment: GPS itself is free and doesn't require any sort of registration. But if you want to send the data anywhere through something like GPRS or GSM you'll need to pay for that.

Comment: Basically you need a GPS tracker not a module. There are various kinds of trackers according to your requirement- personal tracker, vehicle tracking system, object tracker etc. GPS modules doesn't need any subscription but, yes using cellular data to transfer GPS string to server will cost you.

Answer (score 4):

Don't confuse GPS with GPS trackers!

You cannot track any objects using GPS receivers. You need to track them using GPS trackers.

GPS receiver will track GPS satellites and calculate its own position. This service is free. Keep in mind that GPS receiver will not allow you to transfer the location data.

A GPS tracker will have a GPS receiver as its component. It will also allow you to send the location of the tracker. To actually send the location  you'll have to have a data service of some kind, which will cost. So it's not the GPS that needs subscription, it's the data transfer that costs.

Answer (score 1):

> do I have to pay any service (cellular, data,etc) to get my gps working?

No, not a simple GPS, like a hand-held Garmin (other brands are available) or a USB GPS.

If you have a GPS integrated with a phone, and the software relies on other things delivered through the air interface, updated maps, resturants near here, then you will need to pay for that extra service.

Comment: There was something called AGPS... is it still a trend?

Comment: Thanks for you quick comment, I'm not the final user, I want to build a device for tracking , the questions was if the gps to getting working needs any service, for do its work (geolocalization) I know to get that data to my end i need internet or gsm or any wireless service

Comment: @EugeneSh.: If you mean Assisted GPS, then yes. Almanac updates and Ephemeris data are commonly shared over alternative paths, as downloads via the GPS signal are slow.

Comment: @MSalters but with GPS does not apply, doesn't it?

Comment: @BarqLar If you want to download almanac updates and ephemeris data over GPS, it is slow. (I just said the same thing MSalters did.)